# Get Hostname and MAC address from all PCs in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, hostname, mac-address

I'm trying to get the hostname and the MAC address from all PCs in the Active Directory. I know that MAC addresses are not in the Activce Directory. That's why I already used a small script from someone else. The point is that I have to make a list of hostnames, which I can do, but then the other script runs into a problem because some computers are not online.

Can anyone help me get a list with only the pc's that are online?

This is the part that searches the list I create with hostnames.

```
$Computers = Import-CSV C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Computers.txt
$result = @()
foreach ($c in $Computers){
    $nic = Invoke-Command {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"'
    } -ComputerName $c.Name
    $x = New-Object System.Object | select ComputerName, MAC
    $x.Computername = $c.Name
    $x.Mac = $Nic.MACAddress
    $result += $x
}
$result | Export-Csv C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Computers.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

And this is the part that I tried to make search the list and filter out the online computers, which absolutely does not work and I can't figure out how to do it.

```
$Computers = Import-Csv C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Computers.txt
foreach ($c in $Computers) {
    $ping = Test-Connection -Quiet -Count 1
    if ($ping) {
        $c >> (Import-Csv -Delimiter "C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\online.txt")
    } else {
        "Offline"
    }
}
```

Last bit, this is the part I use to create a list of all computers in the Active Directory.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -Properties * |
    select Name > C:\Users\(user)\Desktop\Computers.txt
```

Comment: `$c >> (Import-Csv ...)` doesn't make any sense. What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: That's the point... I'm just a beginner trying to learn a bit of powershell, I thought it could work so that $c was pushed into the online computers txt file if the ping succeeded. But I guess I'm totally wrong.

Comment: `>>` is a redirection operator in practically every shell in existence. These operators are used for writing output to files. `Import-*` cmdlets are (obviously) for importing data from files. So I fail to see how anyone would expect that construct to work. I recommend you immerse yourself in a PowerShell tutorial first and learn the basics of the language (particularly WRT file operations).

Comment: I added that Import-CSV cmdlet because of an output I was getting earlier. That was about something with a warning and something with a header. So I looked that up on the internet and found something about it. So I tried that, but apparently not in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you only want one property from Get-ADComputer don't fetch all
- a computer could have more than one MAC, to avoid an array be returned join them.
- `$result +=` inefficiently rebuilds the array each time, use a PSCustomObject instead.

Try this (untested):
**EDIT: first test connection, get MAC only when online**

```
## Q:\Test\2018\09\18\SO_52381514.ps1

$Computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter {enabled -eq $true} -Property Name).Name

$result = ForEach ($Computer in $Computers){
    If (Test-Connection -Quiet -Count 1 -Computer $Computer){
        [PSCustomPbject]@{
            ComputerName = $Computer
            MAC = (Invoke-Command {
                     (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"').MACAddress -Join ', '
                  } -ComputerName $Computer)
            Online = $True
            DateTime = [DateTime]::Now
        }
    } Else {
        [PSCustomPbject]@{
            ComputerName = $Computer
            MAC = ''
            Online = $False
            DateTime = [DateTime]::Now
        }
    }

}
$result | Export-Csv C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Computers.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks, resulted in: `Unable to find type [PSCustomPbject].
At C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Scrippy.ps1:6 char:6
+     [PSCustomPbject]@{
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (PSCustomPbject:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound`

Comment: Just a typo, should be `[PSCustomObject]@{` corrected.

Comment: Thanks, trying it out now, but takes a while tries to connect to every pc, but a lot of em are turned of so takes quite a while. This is the result code (a lot of explaining above this but too long so post here) `+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (D890:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken`

Comment: See changed script: online try to get MAC when online.

Comment: Trying, it (I guess) tries to connect to every computer so it'll take a while before I can show you the output. Thanks for helping by the way!

Comment: To shorten the list you might append `| Select-Object -First 10` to the `Get-ADComputer`

Comment: `"ComputerName";"MAC";"Online";"DateTime"
"LWD-DC01";"00:50:56:B6:1C:DB";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:28"
"WRD-DC2";"00:50:56:80:0B:4A";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:28"
"LWD-DC1";"00:50:56:80:7E:CA";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:30"
"WRD-DC1";"00:50:56:80:78:2E";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:31"
"LWD-CERTSRV";"00:50:56:80:78:0D";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:31"
"LWD-WEB01";"00:50:56:B6:3E:DD";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:32"
"VERA";"";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:43"
"MARJOLEIN";"00:0C:29:9D:31:8D";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:44"
"L063";"";"True";"18-9-2018 14:57:55"
"VCENTER";"";"False";"18-9-2018 14:57:57"
`

Comment: looks like it's working, but you you think it's possible to only list the name and MAC-Address?

Comment: of course, simply remove the lines `Online=` and `DateTime=`

Comment: this seems to work, just takes a while, thanks! Is there any possibility that the script skips a device if it takes too long to see if it's online? Because I thinks that's the thing that makes the script take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

What about trying something like this:

```
# Get all computers in list that are online
$Computers = Import-Csv C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Computers.txt | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | 
    Where-Object {Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -Quiet}

# Grab the ComputerName and MACAddress
$result = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computers -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter 'ipenabled = "true"' |
    Select-Object -Property PSComputerName, MacAddress

$result | Export-Csv C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Computers.csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Select-Object : Property "Name" cannot be found.
At C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Scrippy.ps1:3 char:5
+     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{LWD-DC01 =D1725 }:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand

Comment: that was the output, looks like it's comparing the LWD-DC1 to every pc?

Comment: Getting another output when using the edit of @LotPings.

Comment: Export-Csv : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'InputObject' because it is null.
At C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Scrippy.ps1:9 char:11
+ $result | Export-Csv C:\Users\admin_stagiair\Desktop\Computers.csv -D ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: @JulianLaLau I based the `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name` on `$c.Name` in the foreach. Do you have an example of what your computers.txt file looks like so that I can further refine this. Sorry for missing the $results vs $results.

Comment: it doesn't really paste as it comes. There is an enter on the top, empty, and then "Name" on the next line, then "----" and then on the next line the names start to come. After every name there are spaces too, which align to the longest name in the file.

Comment: This `
Name           
----           
LWD-DC01       
WRD-DC2        
LWD-DC1        
WRD-DC1        
LWD-CERTSRV    
LWD-WEB01      
VERA           
MARJOLEIN      
L063           
VCENTER        
ODH-PRINT02    
EST-PRINT01    `